# What is »Trööt«?

Tags: meaning, noun, spelling, umlaut, onomatopoeia

The word *Trööt* appears in the title of the article “[Bundesregierung im Fall Yücel. Protest ohne **Trööt**.](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/deniz-yuecel-protest-ohne-troeoet-angela-merkel-und-die-bundesregierung-a-1136643.html)” from *Der Spiegel*.

For context purposes, here is the introductory paragraph of the article:

> Der deutsch-türkische Journalist Deniz Yücel sitzt in der Türkei in U-Haft: Die Kanzlerin zeigt ihre Enttäuschung, Außenminister Gabriel bittet den türkischen Botschafter zum Gespräch. Sind damit ihre Möglichkeiten schon erschöpft?

The word *Trööt* is not listed in any of the online dictionaries in which I looked it up ([dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=tr%C3%B6%C3%B6t); [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/tr%C3%B6%C3%B6t?), [en.pons.com](https://en.pons.com/translate/german-english/tr%C3%B6%C3%B6t), [dictionary.reverso.net](https://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/tr%C3%B6%C3%B6t), [duden.de](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/tr%C3%B6%C3%B6t)).

So, first question, **what does the word *Trööt* mean?**

---

And, second question, **are there any other German words with two consecutive umlaut letters?**

My memory may be failing me, but I don't remember seeing two consecutive umlaut letters in any of the other German words that I came across during the past three years of reading the German press.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Trööt* is an [onomatopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia). It is meant to symbolise the sound that you get out of a trumpet (or other brass instrument) or a party horn. Various types of the latter are frequently present at demonstrations — which could, thus, be considered *Protest mit Trööt.*

Here, obviously, the *Spiegel* is criticising the federal government for protesting in the most silent (and thus unnoticeable) way possible; they might have preferred much clearer statements with more noise.

*Trööt* is neither an established word nor an established spelling. The closest to an established word would be *Tröte* or *tröten* — the former being a party horn the latter making the sound of a party horn.

Usually, double umlauts are not permitted in German spelling and they are shortened to one (compare *Saal – Säle).* However, that means you lose one way of showing that a vowel should be long (the others being adding an *h* — frequently undesirable — and having only a single consonant between two vowels). Because the vowel in *Tröte* and *tröten* is obviously long, the author probably tried to bring the length of the *ö* into writing and doubled it. I probably would have written *Tröt* because a short vowel would invoke a double consonant *(*Trött)* and the difference should therefore be clear enough. But if there is no established word there is no established spelling.

Comment: You find an example of a Trööööööt in the childrens storys about [Benjamin Blümchen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Blümchen). He uses his elephant's trunk as an "organic brass instrument".

Comment: @knut Aber Benjamin macht doch immer *Törööööööö* …?

Comment: Stimmt... Irgendwie habe ich es anders in Erinnerung, aber du hast recht.

Answer (score 2):

Jan's answer is correct. I just want to add some information:

"Trööt" is a so called [Erikativ](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Erikativ) (named after the translator [Erika Fuchs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erika_Fuchs) who introduced the phenomenon in her translations of Walt Disney's comics.)

Usually there are no words with double Umlaut in german. Here it is used in an onomatopoetic manner to create the feeling of a long hooting. (Another example for this technique might be "laaangweilig" (*boring*, literally: "long lasting") which in informal contexts is sometimes written with a long *a* to illustrate how long langweilig is in that case.)